# stack debugging in VS2008

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I am doing some editings with an original source code in OpenCV package to do my tasks. There have been some other compilation errors after my modification. But I've already fixed them. Here comes the last one that I don't know how to remove it:

[image]

moreover, this run-time error does not give any output to the command line to ease the debugging

Is there any solution when bugs come out like this??

PS: the original code is the function cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2 of calib3d.cpp

for convinience, I post the original OpenCV function here:

```
CV_IMPL void cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2( const CvMat* objectPoints,
              const CvMat* imagePoints, const CvMat* A,
              const CvMat* distCoeffs, CvMat* rvec, CvMat* tvec,
              int useExtrinsicGuess )
{
const int max_iter = 20;
Ptr<CvMat> matM, _Mxy, _m, _mn, matL, matJ;

int i, count;
double a[9], ar[9]={1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1}, R[9];
double MM[9], U[9], V[9], W[3];
CvScalar Mc;
double param[6];
CvMat matA = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, a );
CvMat _Ar = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, ar );
CvMat matR = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, R );
CvMat _r = cvMat( 3, 1, CV_64F, param );
CvMat _t = cvMat( 3, 1, CV_64F, param + 3 );
CvMat _Mc = cvMat( 1, 3, CV_64F, Mc.val );
CvMat _MM = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, MM );
CvMat matU = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, U );
CvMat matV = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, V );
CvMat matW = cvMat( 3, 1, CV_64F, W );
CvMat _param = cvMat( 6, 1, CV_64F, param );
CvMat _dpdr, _dpdt;

CV_Assert( CV_IS_MAT(objectPoints) && CV_IS_MAT(imagePoints) &&
    CV_IS_MAT(A) && CV_IS_MAT(rvec) && CV_IS_MAT(tvec) );

count = MAX(objectPoints->cols, objectPoints->rows);
matM = cvCreateMat( 1, count, CV_64FC3 );
_m = cvCreateMat( 1, count, CV_64FC2 );

cvConvertPointsHomogeneous( objectPoints, matM );
cvConvertPointsHomogeneous( imagePoints, _m );
cvConvert( A, &matA );

CV_Assert( (CV_MAT_DEPTH(rvec->type) == CV_64F || CV_MAT_DEPTH(rvec->type) == CV_32F) &&
    (rvec->rows == 1 || rvec->cols == 1) && rvec->rows*rvec->cols*CV_MAT_CN(rvec->type) == 3 );

CV_Assert( (CV_MAT_DEPTH(tvec->type) == CV_64F || CV_MAT_DEPTH(tvec->type) == CV_32F) &&
    (tvec->rows == 1 || tvec->cols == 1) && tvec->rows*tvec->cols*CV_MAT_CN(tvec->type) == 3 );

_mn = cvCreateMat( 1, count, CV_64FC2 );
_Mxy = cvCreateMat( 1, count, CV_64FC2 );

// normalize image points
// (unapply the intrinsic matrix transformation and distortion)
cvUndistortPoints( _m, _mn, &matA, distCoeffs, 0, &_Ar );

if( useExtrinsicGuess )
{
    CvMat _r_temp = cvMat(rvec->rows, rvec->cols,
        CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,CV_MAT_CN(rvec->type)), param );
    CvMat _t_temp = cvMat(tvec->rows, tvec->cols,
        CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,CV_MAT_CN(tvec->type)), param + 3);
    cvConvert( rvec, &_r_temp );
    cvConvert( tvec, &_t_temp );
}
else
{
    Mc = cvAvg(matM);
    cvReshape( matM, matM, 1, count );
    cvMulTransposed( matM, &_MM, 1, &_Mc );
    cvSVD( &_MM, &matW, 0, &matV, CV_SVD_MODIFY_A + CV_SVD_V_T );

    // initialize extrinsic parameters
    if( W[2]/W[1] < 1e-3 || count < 4 )
    {
        // a planar structure case (all M's lie in the same plane)
        double tt[3], h[9], h1_norm, h2_norm;
        CvMat* R_transform = &matV;
        CvMat T_transform = cvMat( 3, 1, CV_64F, tt );
        CvMat matH = cvMat( 3, 3, CV_64F, h );
        CvMat _h1, _h2, _h3;

        if( V[2]*V[2] + V[5]*V[5] < 1e-10 )
            cvSetIdentity( R_transform );

        if( cvDet(R_transform) < 0 )
            cvScale( R_transform, R_transform, -1 );

        cvGEMM( R_transform, &_Mc, -1, 0, 0, &T_transform, CV_GEMM_B_T );

        for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            const double* Rp = R_transform->data.db;
            const double* Tp = T_transform.data.db;
            const double* src = matM->data.db + i*3;
            double* dst = _Mxy->data.db + i*2;

            dst[0] = Rp[0]*src[0] + Rp[1]*src[1] + Rp[2]*src[2] + Tp[0];
            dst[1] = Rp[3]*src[0] + Rp[4]*src[1] + Rp[5]*src[2] + Tp[1];
        }

        cvFindHomography( _Mxy, _mn, &matH );

        if( cvCheckArr(&matH, CV_CHECK_QUIET) )
        {
            cvGetCol( &matH, &_h1, 0 );
            _h2 = _h1; _h2.data.db++;
            _h3 = _h2; _h3.data.db++;
            h1_norm = sqrt(h[0]*h[0] + h[3]*h[3] + h[6]*h[6]);
            h2_norm = sqrt(h[1]*h[1] + h[4]*h[4] + h[7]*h[7]);

            cvScale( &_h1, &_h1, 1./MAX(h1_norm, DBL_EPSILON) );
            cvScale( &_h2, &_h2, 1./MAX(h2_norm, DBL_EPSILON) );
            cvScale( &_h3, &_t, 2./MAX(h1_norm + h2_norm, DBL_EPSILON));
            cvCrossProduct( &_h1, &_h2, &_h3 );

            cvRodrigues2( &matH, &_r );
            cvRodrigues2( &_r, &matH );
            cvMatMulAdd( &matH, &T_transform, &_t, &_t );
            cvMatMul( &matH, R_transform, &matR );
        }
        else
        {
            cvSetIdentity( &matR );
            cvZero( &_t );
        }

        cvRodrigues2( &matR, &_r );
    }
    else
    {
        // non-planar structure. Use DLT method
        double* L;
        double LL[12*12], LW[12], LV[12*12], sc;
        CvMat _LL = cvMat( 12, 12, CV_64F, LL );
        CvMat _LW = cvMat( 12, 1, CV_64F, LW );
        CvMat _LV = cvMat( 12, 12, CV_64F, LV );
        CvMat _RRt, _RR, _tt;
        CvPoint3D64f* M = (CvPoint3D64f*)matM->data.db;
        CvPoint2D64f* mn = (CvPoint2D64f*)_mn->data.db;

        matL = cvCreateMat( 2*count, 12, CV_64F );
        L = matL->data.db;

        for( i = 0; i < count; i++, L += 24 )
        {
            double x = -mn[i].x, y = -mn[i].y;
            L[0] = L[16] = M[i].x;
            L[1] = L[17] = M[i].y;
            L[2] = L[18] = M[i].z;
            L[3] = L[19] = 1.;
            L[4] = L[5] = L[6] = L[7] = 0.;
            L[12] = L[13] = L[14] = L[15] = 0.;
            L[8] = x*M[i].x;
            L[9] = x*M[i].y;
            L[10] = x*M[i].z;
            L[11] = x;
            L[20] = y*M[i].x;
            L[21] = y*M[i].y;
            L[22] = y*M[i].z;
            L[23] = y;
        }

        cvMulTransposed( matL, &_LL, 1 );
        cvSVD( &_LL, &_LW, 0, &_LV, CV_SVD_MODIFY_A + CV_SVD_V_T );
        _RRt = cvMat( 3, 4, CV_64F, LV + 11*12 );
        cvGetCols( &_RRt, &_RR, 0, 3 );
        cvGetCol( &_RRt, &_tt, 3 );
        if( cvDet(&_RR) < 0 )
            cvScale( &_RRt, &_RRt, -1 );
        sc = cvNorm(&_RR);
        cvSVD( &_RR, &matW, &matU, &matV, CV_SVD_MODIFY_A + CV_SVD_U_T + CV_SVD_V_T );
        cvGEMM( &matU, &matV, 1, 0, 0, &matR, CV_GEMM_A_T );
        cvScale( &_tt, &_t, cvNorm(&matR)/sc );
        cvRodrigues2( &matR, &_r );
    }
}

cvReshape( matM, matM, 3, 1 );
cvReshape( _mn, _mn, 2, 1 );

// refine extrinsic parameters using iterative algorithm
CvLevMarq solver( 6, count*2, cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,max_iter,FLT_EPSILON), true);
cvCopy( &_param, solver.param );

for(;;)
{
    CvMat *matJ = 0, *_err = 0;
    const CvMat *__param = 0;
    bool proceed = solver.update( __param, matJ, _err );
    cvCopy( __param, &_param );
    if( !proceed || !_err )
        break;
    cvReshape( _err, _err, 2, 1 );
    if( matJ )
    {
        cvGetCols( matJ, &_dpdr, 0, 3 );
        cvGetCols( matJ, &_dpdt, 3, 6 );
        cvProjectPoints2( matM, &_r, &_t, &matA, distCoeffs,
                          _err, &_dpdr, &_dpdt, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        cvProjectPoints2( matM, &_r, &_t, &matA, distCoeffs,
                          _err, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    }
    cvSub(_err, _m, _err);
    cvReshape( _err, _err, 1, 2*count );
}
cvCopy( solver.param, &_param );

_r = cvMat( rvec->rows, rvec->cols,
    CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,CV_MAT_CN(rvec->type)), param );
_t = cvMat( tvec->rows, tvec->cols,
    CV_MAKETYPE(CV_64F,CV_MAT_CN(tvec->type)), param + 3 );

cvConvert( &_r, rvec );
cvConvert( &_t, tvec );
}
```

I guess it is pretty complicated! :(

Comment: please post some code to explain your problem better. have your tried debugging using breakpoints?

Comment: as I mentioned, that was the function "cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams2 of calib3d.cpp" and OpenCV is open-source. I also tried breakpoints already

Comment: most of the times the problem is not in the library, its how you pass the arguments which gives rise to errors related to possible memory leak. Are you sure you are passing all the arguments correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going wrong here is that in one of the function calls the compiler is putting local variables, including `tvecmat_ar` on the stack, but in a debug build it is also putting some guard blocks after the variables.  When the function is about to return and the stack is popped the debug runtime checks the status of the guard blocks.  If they have a different value then this generates the stack corruption error that you are seeing.  So this means that code in that function is corrupting memory.  I would bet that you are writing to an array beyond the size of that array.

You haven't attached the source of the code containing the variable that it is warning you about, so it's impossible to tell any further, but I would advise checking all array allocations and indexes in your function.

Comment: thank you for the clear & comprehensive explanation! I hope to finish this problem from this advice

Comment: @Mr the_mandrill: assume that I have a float array, and during function computation, one array's element exceeds float number. Will this also create this error??

Comment: No, that should be fine -- you will get arithmetic overflow, but it won't go beyond the size of the float type.